# Flash Thin Client

Tags: citrix, thin-client

I have an old thin client that was going to be discarded from a friend's company - as they are upgrading their thin clients. I was given this old one to demonstrate to the CEO the benefits of using thin clients with citrix. I need to know how to flash it so that I can use it in our citrix environment. I have setup the desktop session on the citrix server - I just need to know where and how to flash it so that it can be used.

The model is an IBM NetVista 2200 (I think - IBM don't exactly make it easy to find out on the box).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never used that particular model, but typically, you may find the flash attached as either a MTD or IDE device.

If you open it up and find that it contains something like a Compact Flash card, it is most likely connected to the IDE and can be used just like any other IDE drive. That would be your easiest way to flash it.

If you open it up and find that it looks like a fat chip, it is most likely an MTD device. You will then need some specialised tools to flash it, like you are flashing a BIOS device.

Hopefully this can help you get started.